# Semaphore questions

Tags: c, semaphore

To practice Semaphore I wrote some basic codes to understand this concept

The server code is this

```
#include "MySem.h"
#include "MyShm.h"
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void signalHandler(int signum);

int shmid = 0;
int *shmaddr = 0;

int semidServ = 0;
int semidClnt = 0;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int req = 0;
    int res = 0;

    union semun semunBuf;
    shmid = createShm(MY_SHM_KEY);
    shmaddr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    semidServ = creatSem(MY_SEM_SERV_KEY);
    semunBuf.val = 0;
    semctl(semidServ, 0, SETVAL, semunBuf);

    semidClnt = creatSem(MY_SEM_CLNT_KEY);
    semunBuf.val = 1;
    semctl(semidClnt, 0, SETVAL, semunBuf);

    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);

    while (1) {
        puts("Wait ...");

        lockSem(semidServ);
        memcpy(&req, shmaddr, sizeof(int));
        res = req + 1;
        memcpy(shmaddr, &res, sizeof(int));
        unlockSem(semidClnt);

        printf("Request: %d\n", req);
        printf("Response: %d\n", res);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the client code is this

```
 #include "MySem.h"
    #include "MyShm.h"
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/sem.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    
    void signalHandler(int signum);
    
    int shmid = 0;
    int *shmaddr = NULL;
    
    int semidServ = 0;
    int semidClnt = 0;
    
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        int req = 0;
        int res;
    
        shmid = openShm(MY_SHM_KEY);
        shmaddr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    
        semidServ = openSem(MY_SEM_SERV_KEY);
        semidClnt = openSem(MY_SEM_CLNT_KEY);
    
        signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    
        while (1) {
            printf("<<");
            scanf("%d", &req);
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stdin);
    
            lockSem(semidClnt);
            memcpy(shmaddr, &req, sizeof(int));
            unlockSem(semidServ);
    
            lockSem(semidClnt);
            memcpy(&res, shmaddr, sizeof(int));
            unlockSem(semidClnt);
    
            printf(">> %d\n", res);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

what I'm wondering is that in client code right after scanf function both semaphores are locked to value 0 by lockSem(semidClnt); the communication still works between server and client? Is there any my misunderstanding of this code?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. I don't know what you are asking. /// Re "*semaphores are locked*", "Lock" isn't a term that applies to semaphores. Semaphores have a value, they aren't locked or unlocked.

Comment: We want to see the full code for your custom functions (e.g. `openSem`, `lockSem`, etc.). We want an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we want a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download it and build and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Comment: @Craig Estey, The OP didn't mention any error, runtime or otherwise. It's unclear what they are asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're asking. I think you simply wants us to review the code.

It's fine, but I would simplify the client.

---

First of all, semaphores can't be locked. You could use a semaphore as a mutex, but you're not doing that. So referring to the semaphore as being locked makes no sense here.

In my simplified version, I will also use two semaphores.

- `request_sem`, which has two states:

  | state | meaning | initial |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 0 | No request pending. | Initial state. |
  | 1 | Request pending. |  |

  `request_sem` is just a new name for `semidServ`.
- `response_sem`, which has has two states:

  | state | meaning | initial |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 0 | No response pending. | Initial state. |
  | 1 | Response ready. |  |

  `response_sem` replaces which replaces `semidClnt`. It has entirely different states than `semidClnt` in the original program, and it has a different initial state. It was very complicated to describe the states of `semidClnt`, a clear indicator that an improvement could be made.

---

The server code is left untouched (except for the names).

```c
// Wait for a request to come in (wait for `request_sem` to be 1).
// Indicate no request is pending (set `request_sem` to 0).
// `response_sem` is expected to be 0 when this returns
// so that we can set it to 1 when the response is ready.
sem_wait(request_sem);

// Service the request.
memcpy(&req, shmaddr, sizeof(int));
res = req + 1;
memcpy(shmaddr, &res, sizeof(int));

// Indicate the response is ready (set `response_sem` to 1).
sem_post(response_sem);
```

---

The client code is simplified.

```c
// `request_sem` is expected to be 0 here.
// `response_sem` is expected to be 0 here.

req = ...;

// Send request.
memcpy(shmaddr, &req, sizeof(int));

// Let the server know a request was made (set `request_sem` to 1).
sem_post(request_sem);

// Wait for a response to come in (wait for `response_sem` to be 1).
// Indicate no response is pending (set `response_sem` to 0).
// `request_sem` is expected to be 0 when this returns
// so that we can set it to 1 when we make our next request.
sem_wait(response_sem);

// Receive response.
memcpy(&res, shmaddr, sizeof(int));
```

---

We can easily verify our assumptions ("X is expected to be Y") and see that this code works properly, while being much simpler.